# scrapy css selector not working to extract the data from a website

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

**I am going to scrape the "HealthUnblock" website with the following URL "https://healthunlocked.com" but I cannot see any output. I am going to use the CSS selector to extract the title of each post in the following format. I used response.css and selectorgadget to see the relevant CSS tag and class**

```
start_urls = ['https://healthunlocked.com/positivewellbeing/posts#popular']

    def parse(self, response):
      
        
        title = response.css('.results-post .results-post__title').css('::text').extract()

        yield title
```

**And the log is**

```
2020-12-26 00:12:08 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.4.1 started (bot: Testtutorial)
2020-12-26 00:12:08 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.6.1.0, libxml2 2.9.10, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 20.3.0, Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  3 2020, 21:29:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 19.1.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1h  22 Sep 2020), cryptography 3.1.1, Platform Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
2020-12-26 00:12:08 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
2020-12-26 00:12:08 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'Testtutorial',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'Testtutorial.spiders',
 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True,
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['Testtutorial.spiders']}
2020-12-26 00:12:08 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: df08a57d9bb3287d
2020-12-26 00:12:08 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2020-12-26 00:12:08 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2020-12-26 00:12:08 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2020-12-26 00:12:08 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2020-12-26 00:12:08 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-12-26 00:12:08 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-12-26 00:12:08 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-12-26 00:12:08 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://healthunlocked.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2020-12-26 00:12:09 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://healthunlocked.com/positivewellbeing/posts#popular> (referer: None)
2020-12-26 00:12:09 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider must return request, item, or None, got 'list' in <GET https://healthunlocked.com/positivewellbeing/posts#popular>
2020-12-26 00:12:09 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-12-26 00:12:09 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 493,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 36347,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 0.72626,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 26, 0, 12, 9, 354888),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 2,
 'log_count/ERROR': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 26, 0, 12, 8, 628628)}
2020-12-26 00:12:09 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content you look for are heavily dynamic and not available in page source (ctrl + u). Try the following instead to get the titles from that site:

```
import json

start_urls = ['https://solaris.healthunlocked.com/posts/positivewellbeing/popular']

def parse(self, response):
    for item in json.loads(response.body):
        yield {"title":item['title']}
```

Comment: would you please share any references if you have for this coding style with JSON because I need to extract more fields from this website. Thanks